# Show only specific representative point using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, cluster-computing

This question is quite basic about `ggplot2`, but I could not find the
answer elsewhere.

I want to have a line graph(built from all the data) and to add points only for specific cases.

Example:

```
x= seq(1:10)
y = 2*x
df = data.frame(x,y)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_line()
```

Now I would like to emphasise some of the date by points, for example all the y points which can be divided without remainder by 6.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
x  <- seq(1:10)
y  <- 2*x
df <-  data.frame(x,y)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+
  geom_line()+ 
  geom_point(data=df[df$y%%6==0,],size=5,colour="red")
```